# How to add a video (not from youtube) to a flutter/dart app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I've tried ways of doing it, but I really lack knowledge of flutter and I don't understand what people say in video and stuff, all I need is a video that's not from youtube, to be played in the app screen (not the main screen)

this is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Video Player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package to add the player.

It is a Flutter plugin for displaying inline videos with other Flutter widgets on Android, iOS, and the web.